# subprocess with double quotations

Tags: python, subprocess

In python have to run the following perl command with subprocess.

perl command:

```
perl dcm.pl -r ona_sql sql="select something from table where name='somename'" header=no
```

I need to escape the quotations, but can't get it to work.

The following example would make the most sense for me, but it doesn't work either.

```
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/perl", "/opt/ona/bin/dcm.pl", "-r", "ona_sql", "sql=\"select something from table where name='somename'\"", "header=no"]).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
```

results in:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/perl', '/opt/ona/bin/dcm.pl', '-r', 'ona_sql', 'sql="select something from table where name=\'somename\'"', 'header=no']' returned non-zero exit status 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use triple quotes to enclose string literals with both single quotes and double quotes:

```
subprocess.check_output(['perl', '/opt/ona/bin/dcm.pl', '-r', 'ona_sql', '''sql="select something from table where name='somename'"''', 'header=no'])
```

Comment: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/perl', '/opt/ona/bin/dcm.pl', '-r', 'ona_sql', "sql=select something from table where name='somename'", 'header=no']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Comment: That argument list looks correct to me. Are you the command works if you run it directly from the command line?

Comment: This does not work too. It somehow strips the quotations from the sql command. it should be 'sql="select something from table where name='somename' " '

Comment: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['perl', '/opt/ona/bin/dcm.pl', '-r', 'ona_sql', 'sql="select semething from table where name=\'somename\'"', 'header=no']' returned non-zero exit status 3

Comment: Hmm and you are sure that the command runs fine if it's executed directly from the command line right?

Comment: Thanks for your effort, maybe you see why this is driving me crazy - now it inserts a escape character into the sql and it wont work

Comment: The escape character is there for display purpose only. It is not actually sent as part of the command.

Comment: I guess it has something to do how dcm.pl returns the data and somehow subprocess cant handle it. I got it to work by creating a bash script where the perl command is executed, stored in a var and echoed. If i call the bash script with subprocess, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes instead:

```
'sql="select something from table where name=\'somename\'"'
```